# Stream urls of live tv channels from their official website

Tags: android, url, live-streaming, vitamio

I am working an android app in which live tv channels will be played.
I am using `vitmio` api for this purpose.
I am able to play some of channels using this `api`  (using mms and rtsp urls).
but some of channels I am not able to played yet. I am using url helper for getting rtsp urls from source website. the url helper is giving me rtsp url but those rtsp urls I am unable to played.
like for example I have a channel
[GEO TV](http://live.geo.tv/live.aspx)

I am getting its rtsp like this one

```
rtmp://cdn.eboundservices.com/geonews?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTIvMTgvMjAxMyA3OjU4OjEzIEFNJmhhc2hfdmFsdWU9M01CbWVpbVV6eUtQUzRhWFd5UllvZz09JnZhbGlkbWludXRlcz0yMA==/geonews_sub
```

but vitmio media player is not playing this rtmp url
what should I do to play this channel using vitmio player ???

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 String link = "rtmp://cdn.eboundservices.com/geonews?wmsAuthSign=c2VydmVyX3RpbWU9MTIvMTgvMjAxMyA3OjU4OjEzIEFNJmhhc2hfdmFsdWU9M01CbWVpbVV6eUtQUzRhWFd5UllvZz09JnZhbGlkbWludXRlcz0yMA==/geonews_sub";


videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(link);
videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

Comment: its not playing i have done it before using vitmiopalyer

Comment: Have you the right permissions in your manifest @NoamanAkram ?

Comment: yes i have added permission     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 1):

you should use vitamio library for this issue vitamio library from here http://www.vitamio.org/en/docs/Basic/2013/0509/4.html

If links are `rtsp://` then you can easily use `MediaPlayer`. Try something like this:

```
MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer(); 
m.setDataSource("rtsp://host.name.com/stream/name"); 
m.prepare(); 
m.start();
```

Comment: i am getting this exception i have used vitmio [rtmp @ 0x1328b30] Unknown connect error (unsupported authentication method?)

Comment: "Unsupported authentication method" seems pretty self-explanatory. The library does not support the stream you're trying to play. I don't know what you expect anyone here to do about it.